# Unable to display text from Resource file

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, resources

I have created a web part in sharepoint. I want display the text from resource keys.

For sample code I have created label and fetching the text from resource file.

Code is:

```
<td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblProjectName" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:OIPLBIntranet,lblProjectNameText%>"></asp:Label>
</td>
```

There are two resource files in application form.

1.OIPLBIntranet
2.OIPLBIntranet.en-us

But the text associated with key `lblProjectNameText` is not displayed. Instead it is displaying text as it is assigned in declaration.

What should I do?

Comment: where did you deployed your resource files?

Comment: Actually I do not know where does that files are placed when it is deployed. I have given a site collection url in deploy path. Where to look for these files?

Comment: In the article here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee696750.aspx you will see full details

Answer (score 0):

Resources are not working in asp controls. Don't do like that. Set it in your *.cs file.